# how can I made a 12vdc to 19vdc booster/regulator?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc, dc-dc-converter

This is a fairly specific question, but I think the answer could probably be applied to various voltages.

I would like to make a circuit that will take in a 12-14volt source (from a lead acid) that outputs a regulated 19volts at 5+ Amps.  Would this be easy to do myself?  If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need a *boost regulator*, check this one out from TI.  There's a reference schematic on the first page http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps40210.pdf

Or maybe this module from linear, it's a little easier to design: http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/4607fb.pdf

Page 21 has the ref schematic for that one.